# Magic methods and definition order

Tags: python, trie, magic-methods

I'm looking at the source code for a [trie implementation](https://github.com/bdimmick/python-trie/blob/master/trie.py)

On lines 80-85:

```
def keys(self, prefix=[]):
    return self.__keys__(prefix)

def __keys__(self, prefix=[], seen=[]):
    result = []
    etc.
```

1. **What is `def __keys__`?** Is that a magic object that is self-created? If so, is this poor code?  Or does `__keys__` exist as a standard Python magic method? I can't find it anywhere in the Python documentation, though.
2. **Why is it legal for the function to call `self.__keys__` before `def __keys__` is even instantiated?** Wouldn't `def __keys__` have to go before `def keys` (since `keys` calls `__keys__`)?

Comment: `def keys` defines the `keys` function, it doesn't actually call `self.__keys__` until someone calls it, e.g. `trie.keys()`. By that point, `__keys__` will have been defined.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The compilation of a class in Python is done way before the class is instantiated.

Whenever class type is created, the body of the class block is compiled and executed. Then, all the functions are transformed either into bound handles (normal functions) or into classmethod/staticmethod objects. Then, when a new instance is created, content of the type's `__dict__` is copied over to the instance (and bound handles are transformed into methods).

Therefore, at the moment of calling `instance.keys()`, the instance already has both `keys` and `__keys__` methods.

Also, there is no `__keys__` method in any data mode, as far as I know.

Comment: Your description of how objects are created isn't very accurate when applied to new-style classes (which are the only kind in Python 3). While the linked class doesn't have `object` as a base, it probably should! In new-style classes, functions defined don't get turned into anything special (unless they're decorated). It's only when they're looked up on the an instance that they get bound (via the descriptor protocol). Further, nothing is copied from the class `__dict__` to the instance's `__dict__`, as attribute lookups will check in the class dict (and the dicts of any bases) if necessary.

Comment: @Blckknght as far as I know, everything is still copied over to the instance, because if you try class variable, you can modify a copy in the instance without modfying the class variable. Also, function do get changed into bound objects in python2 even with new style classes (Foo.method is a bound function because it requires Foo to be first argument).

Comment: Nothing is copied automatically into the instance dict. Your "modified" class variable is probably being rebound as an instance variable so that it shadows the old value, rather than actually being modified in place. Regarding methods, you're partly right that in Python 2 you get a special kind of "unbound" method when you look up a method on the class, but you're wrong about when this happens. It's only when you do the lookup that the binding happens. If you look in the class `__dict__`, you'll see the unmodified function.

Answer (score 3):

All of the real *"magic methods"* are in the [data model documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html); `__keys__` isn't one of them. The [style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) says:

> Never invent such names; only use them as documented.

so yes, making up a new one is bad form (the convention would have been to call it `_keys`).

The second part of your question doesn't make sense; even if this wasn't a class, there is no need to define methods and functions in the order they're called. As long as they exist *by the time the call actually gets made*, it's not a problem. I tend to define public methods before private ones, even though the former may call the latter, simply for the reader's convenience.

Answer (score 2):

For your second question, it is legal, the functions for a class are defined when the class gets defined , so you can be sure both functions would be defined before `keys()` is called, the logic also applies to normal functions, we can do -

```
>>> def a():
...     b()
...
>>> def b():
...     print("In B()")
...
>>> a()
In B()
```

This is legal because both `a()` and `b()` are defined before `a()` is called. It would only be illegal , if you try to call `a()` before `b()` gets defined. Please note defining a function does not automatically call it , and python does not validate at time of definition of function whether any functions used in a function is defined or not (untill runtime, when the function is called and in that case it throws a NameError)

For your first question, I do not know of any such magic methods called `__keys__()` , cannot find it in documentation either.

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no magic method named `__keys__()`, so as you suspected this is just poor naming.
2. The code in the class definition can be in any order.  All the matters that the definition has been made by the time the actual call is made downstream.

Answer (score 0):

There is no magic method named `__keys__`, so its just a wrong naming convention. Looking at the code, the author just wanted to have a private method which is used internally, and also from the public method `keys`. As you can see `__keys__` accepts an additional argument.

About the second question, there is no need that you define the functions in the same order as they called. It will be available by the time code is compiled.